# multi-language website with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multilingual

I wanted to know how to make my web a multi-language website using angularjs so it won't load the whole page on click.
i thought making a controller that have an array that has a language code for the whole site on each outer index like.

- `language [0]` has name : name, last : last
- `language [1]` has the same in other language and when you will
  choose english the value of the ouuter index changes from 0 to 1 and
  so on...

what is the best way to do it?

```
language[0]{name:name,last:last}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend using angular-translate
[angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate)

Answer (score 0):

I know Im quite late but i think one way i would do it is using json format and maybe link the data in model using angular, something like this :

```
{
  "config": {
    "default": "en"
  },
  "language": {
    "en": {
      "title": "Title",
      "home": "Home",
      "contact": "Contact-us"
    },
    "fr": {
      "title": "Titre",
      "home": "Menu Principal",
      "contact": "Contactez nous",
    }
  }
}
```

Consider voting for a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Along with [the approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45609124/6270421) by "Ali BAGHO" if you can create a custom angularJS filter that can take arguments which is a selected language, you can translate the page dynamically on a button click. since filters are undergo $digest cycle on every model associated changes it will dynamically update the DOM with new translated text.

You can also refer to this link for [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51720981/6270421) on how this can be implemented in Angular5